MySQL 8.0.36 FULLTEXT index search not returning results with strings over 10 characters in length
I recently added MySQL 8.0.36 to my local WAMP server and all has seemed good, though it would appear that FULLTEXT index searches don't return any results if the search keyword is over 10 characters in length.
For example: If I have a single entry in the table that contains "We have experience with this" and my SQL is as below, I get the result returned.
SELECT * FROM searchindex WHERE siteId = '1' AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('experience' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

If I update the entry to read "We are experienced with this" and change the SQL to ...AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('experienced' IN BOOLEAN MODE); I now get no results returned.
The table is InnoDB and i have tried the collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
I have rebuilt the table and index in a separate database and still experiencing the same behavior.
If I convert the table to MyISAM then I am able to return results as expected. The issue return when converting back to InnoDB
Any pointers to what may be going on or what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Can you reproduce this at db-fiddle?

It would seem to work as expected there. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eTdwC93ZpQo63VJD5g3yau/0

what does select @@innodb_ft_max_token_size show?

@ysth Ha! That was it! It was set to 10. I changed that value in my.ini and re-saved the index and all seems to be working again. Thanks so much!

Big thanks to ysth. My problem was that innodb_ft_max_token_size was set to 10.
Updating this in my.ini and resaving the index solved the problem.
